# How to edit the new article form in joomla v1.7

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I am trying to edit the New article form in joomla .I want to set the **Access** field to be set to **registered** auotmatically and the **Featured** to be **Yes** without the user even doing it.so meaning i will remove those fields from the form.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can go into 'General Settings', when you go to the Article Manager and set that stuff from there.
You may not be able to set the Access, but I'm almost positive you can set Featured.